# Problem with textfields and scene transition + cocos2d

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sdk, cocos2d-iphone

I am having problems with my textfield not flowing with the scene transistion. Basically my scene is transition with this call:

```
Scene* gs = [[[QuestionsScene alloc] initWithPage:2] autorelease];      
[[Director sharedDirector] replaceScene: [SlideInRTransition transitionWithDuration:0.5 scene: gs]];
```

However in my init i have a textfield called here:

```
    [answerBox setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [answerBox setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentLeft];
    [answerBox setContentHorizontalAlignment:UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft];
    [answerBox setClearsOnBeginEditing:YES];
    [answerBox setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect]; 

    [answerBox setDelegate:self];
    [answerBox setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyDone];
    [answerBox setAutocapitalizationType:UITextAutocapitalizationTypeWords];
    [[[Director sharedDirector] openGLView] addSubview: answerBox];
```

The textbox does not follow the transition, it just sits there into the next scene. Anyone have an idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Just read up on Cocos2d 0.9 alpha release. This has a feature to add a `UIKitLayer`. Neat :-), that is pretty much what you will be wanting to do.

Comment: that's good to know, basically what i am doing now, it hiding and removing the text field whenever i am changing scenes, doesn't really follow the transition but it'll do for now.

Answer (score 0):

You add the answerBox to the openGLView directly, not to the scene. So naturally when the scene changes, the answerBox is not affected.

If you use a UILabel, you cannot add it as a child on a CocosNode object, so you can't add it to your scene.

Look into using the Cocos2d label class instead. Either use [Label](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/latest-stable/interface_label.html) or it's faster cousin [LabelAtlas](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/latest-stable/interface_label_atlas.html)

I haven't checked how Cocos2d manages its views. Perhaps there might be another option? You can try on the cocos2d forums.

Answer (score 0):

For this solution, i just did removed the textbox upon transition

```
[nameBox removeFromSuperview];
```

and reappear when it comes back to the scene:

```
[nameBox becomeFirstResponder];
```

which there was a smoother transition to this though.